# Polymorphism using interface

Tags: c#

A class BasePrintHandler as been derived from the interface IPrintHandler and implements required functionality. This is provided as a library

Application has to provide a functionality(SendToPrint) which is different from the library. Now For this I have derived a class from BaseClass as well as from the interface.

For this I have created an example

```
interface IPrintHandler
{
    void SetPage();
    void SendToPrint();
}

class BasePrintHandler : IPrintHandler
{
    void IPrintHandler.SendToPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in the base print handler");
    }

    void IPrintHandler.SetPage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in the setpage");
    }
}

class ChildPrintHandler : BasePrintHandler,IPrintHandler
{
    private BasePrintHandler m_Printhandler;

    public ChildPrintHandler()
    {
        m_Printhandler = new BasePrintHandler();
    }

    void IPrintHandler.SendToPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in the derive class");
        IPrintHandler aPRinthandler = m_Printhandler as IPrintHandler;
        aPRinthandler.SendToPrint();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPrintHandler aLayouthandler = new ChildPrintHandler();
        aLayouthandler.SendToPrint();

        aLayouthandler.SetPage();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

1. How good is this design , the class derived from the baseclass and as well from the interface and implement only the required functionality - SendToPrint.

Comment: ask it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ you can get more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too bad, but in this kind of model I prefer to do it slightly differently.  Your base class may implement some default behaviour (that can be completely replaced), or it might implement some *mostly required* behaviour, where the subclass must remember to call the base-class.  When I write interfaces and provide a base-class to provide a boiler-plate implementation, I go a step further with protected overrides:

```
public interface IPrinter
{
    void SetPage();
    void SendToPrint();
} // eo interface IPrinter


public class BasePrinter : IPrinter /* Could well be abstract */
{
     protected virtual void SetPageImpl() { }      /* Also could be abstract */
     protected virtual void SendToPrintImpl() { }  /* ........ditto .....    */


     // IPrinter implementation
     public void SetPage()
     {
         SetPageImpl();
         // can do other stuff here.  Will always be called!
     } // eo SetPage


     public void SendToPrint()
     {
         SendToPrintImpl();
         // ditto
     }
}  // eo class BasePrinter


public class ChildPrinter : BasePrinter
{
     // we only do something different when setting a page
     protected override void SetPageImpl()
     {
        // ChildPrinter-specifics
     } // eo SetPageImpl
} // eo class ChildPrinter
```

This way, we keep the contract of the interface, provide boiler-plate code that will always be called, and allow other classes to change the behaviour.  I tend to implement the above with *abstract* protected functions in most cases.  I also don't have to remember to call the base-class implementation, or in which order (start or end of my override?)

Comment: In the example which I have provided, the ChildPrintHandler implements only the sendtoPrint, but if a instance of the ChildPrintHandler is created,the instance can call SetPage also. Is it possible to tell me how this is possible?

Comment: You could derive another class from `BasePrinter` (say `DefaultPrinter`) that implemented things as your current one does.  `ChildPrinter` could then create an instance of this.